# how to use Minitest to handle a json input for record changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

The following two separate tests are handling their respective json string

```
    assert_no_difference('Article.count') do
      post array_api_v1_articles_path, params: @existing, as: :json
    end
{ "items": { [
  { code: "00083", "sell_price": 0.01 }, ...
] } }

    assert_changes articles(:fifty_five).sell_price, from: 9.99, to: 0.01 do
      post array_api_v1_articles_path, params: @existing, as: :json
    end  

{ "items": { [
  { code: "00084", "sell_price": 0.01 }, ...
] } }
```

While the former case can measure the change in `count`, the latter - while returning the new value with `puts` commands in the method reflects the change

```
puts @article.sell_price
0.01
```

, the asserts fails: `0.999e1 didn't change. Expected 9.99 to not be equal to 9.99.`

How should this test be cast then?

Comment: Try rounding the numbers you're comparing, it might be falling in some decimal difference, which isn't being printed completely by Minitest. Just if you can do so, if rounding or casting isn't possible, then try using `==`.

Comment: Try doing `assert_changes articles(:fifty_five).reload.sell_price, ...`, probably the instance is in memory and the post request is changing the database but you are not re-reading the database for the new value

Comment: yes, I also tried that, getting `0.999e1 didn't change. Expected 9.99 to not be equal to 9.99.`  But the reload was the missing ingredient.  Posted a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the condition in a lamdba:

```
article = articles(:fifty_five)
assert_changes ->{ article.sell_price }, from: 9.99, to: 0.01 do
  post array_api_v1_articles_path, params: @existing, as: :json
  article.reload
end
```

This lambda will be evaluated before and after the block is run.

What you're doing is passing the instance of Float (or Decimal if you're doing it right) which doesn't actually change. Numerics are actually immutable.

While you can use `assert_equal` the failure message is a lot less useful.

Comment: I just want to emphasize @max's aside about using decimal instead of float for anything involving currency.

I'll give a real world example: My pharmacy website showed I owed $X.00000000001 for a prescription. 

In addition to being embarrassing and causing rounding errors, using a float can cause `assert_not_equal` to pass with a false positive even if the tested code is wrong (e.g. `1 != 0` is expected, but the actual comparison is `1 != 1.0000001`, which is true, but not what is wanted for that particular test case.)

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error

```
assert_changes articles(:fifty_five).reload.sell_price [...] do
assert_changes articles(:fifty_five).sell_price [...] do
```

blocks never worked.  It seems the block is the issue. A pithier

```
post array_api_v1_articles_path, params: @params, as: :json
assert_equal 0.01, articles(:fifty_five).reload.sell_price
```

generates the assertion with success.  `reload` the fixture...